How does [Vue Warn] hide itself from being displayed as warning location in Vue/Vite Projects?
When I do something problematic in Vue, I get a warning from Vue.
//myComposable.ts

export function useMyComposable() {
    const firstVal = inject("not provided") // vue warns me about this!
}

Console Output:

[Vue warn]: injection "not provided" not found. - myComposable.ts:4

It shows the correct location of my code (myComposable.ts).
However, when I try to implement such a custom warning function myself, I get the location of my wrapper function code (customWarning.ts) instead of myComposable.ts:
//myComposable.ts

import { myCustomWarning } from './customWarning'

export function useMyComposable() {
    const firstVal = inject("not provided") // vue warns me about this!
    myCustomWarning("there is no value for key 'not provided'") 
}

//customWarning.ts

export function myCustomWarning(msg: string) {
    console.warn("[Custom warn]: " + msg)
}

Console Output:

[Vue warn]: injection "not provided" not found. - myComposable.ts:6
[Custom warn]: injection "not provided" not found. - customWarning.ts:4

I understand that this is the default behaviour of console.warn() as documented in MDN Web docs.
However, I also see from the Vue source code (Line 74 here), that they use console.warn() themselves internally.

So I am wondering, how can their call to console.warn() hide that it is called from a wrapper function?
I am sure it has to do with Vue being built into one dist file / folder, and the code being compiled by vite, but how does it work exactly?

Please, provide a way to reproduce. Besides other things, these could be problems with source maps as these .ts files don't really exist at runtime. There is no default behaviour of console.warn, it depends on a specific implementation. You didn't mention a browser, while it's very specific to it. In Chrome-based ones full stack trace is available for warn output that gives a better picture. It's not reproducible https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-rdkep4 . The answer is that Vue has no direct control over call stack in warn() calls and it's very specific to the conditions on your side

@EstusFlask Thanks for your response! Your StackBlitz link reproduces the issue for me!
I am on mac with chrome 126. If I load the stackblitz page for the first time, then open the console, the source file name is 'vue.js'. If I open the console in the loading phase or reload with the console open, it becomes 'myComposable.ts'.

I could reproduce this in Edge but not Opera. This is how source maps and specific console implementation work. The entries for vue.js... chunk from the stack don't have a map and are dimmed and collapsed.  You can fully expand call stack and see that warn() is still there. This behaviour is determined by this option https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/settings/ignore-list

I see! With ignore list (under chrome-based browsers), I can determine which frames are automatically hidden. Tools like Vue with Vite that use a build process, can use the x_google_ignoreList extension to tell devtools to hide certain frames, and I can use the settings to tell devtools about my own.
Found the additional info here:
https://web.dev/articles/source-maps
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/source-maps/
